# How to remove any duplicates in python output

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a python dictionary maker that I am working on. I have been piecing it together but I need help. When I make it submit to a text file, or the output, it has duplicate words before new ones. For example this could be the output one time:
a
a
a
b
a
c

I need the output to be
a
b
c

Or (to help those that dont get it) another output example is:
abc
cba
abc
cba
bca

when it should be:
aaa
aab
aac
aba
abb
abc
aca
acb
acc
baa

and so forth.

Can anyone help me? this is the code I have so far (it saves to a .txt file named wordlist.txt)

```
import string, random

minimum=input('Please enter the minimum length of any give word to be generated: ')
maximum=input('Please enter the maximum length of any give word to be generated: ')
wmaximum=input('Please enter the max number of words to be generate in the dictionary: ')

alphabet =raw_input("What characters should we use to generate the random words?: ")
string=''
FILE = open("wordlist.txt","w")
for count in xrange(0,wmaximum):
  for x in random.sample(alphabet,random.randint(minimum,maximum)):
      string+=x
  FILE.write(string+'\n')
  string=''
print''
FILE.close()
print 'DONE!'
end=raw_input("Press Enter to exit")
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Include sample input and sample output.

Comment: [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) should help you out.

Answer (score 2):

Are you just trying to count unique words in a file? Why not:

```
with open("wordlist.txt","r") as wf:
   content = wf.read()
   words = [w.strip() for w in content.split(" ")]  # or however you want to do this
   # sets do not allow duplicates 
   # constructor will automatically strip duplicates from input
   unique_words = set(words)

print unique_words
```

Comment: You're going to have to be a bit more specific. What's the error? What is the script you're running? And can you give a few lines of a file enough to test on?

Answer (score 0):

you can use python set collection to resolve the issue

below line you can add after getting alphabet

```
new_alpha=''.join(set(alphabet))
```

in below line new_alpha needs to pass

```
for x in random.sample(new_alpha,random.randint(minimum,maximum)):
```

Below is entire code :-

```
import string, random

minimum=input('Please enter the minimum length of any give word to be generated: ')
maximum=input('Please enter the maximum length of any give word to be generated: ')
wmaximum=input('Please enter the max number of words to be generate in the dictionary: ')

alphabet =raw_input("What characters should we use to generate the random words?: ")
new_alpha=''.join(set(alphabet))
string=''
FILE = open("wordlist.txt","w")
for count in xrange(0,wmaximum):
  for x in random.sample(new_alpha,random.randint(minimum,maximum)):
      string+=x
  FILE.write(string+'\n')
  string=''
print''
FILE.close()
print 'DONE!'
end=raw_input("Press Enter to exit")
```

Comment: So what would be the final code? I am not good with python... I keep getting errors when i try this.